# Cannot target an image within a widget

Tags: css

I have an image which is pulled in using a widget in a sidebar and for some reason I can't seem to target it with CSS....

I have tried various ways e.g.

```
.jetpack-image-container img{
```

and

```
[title~="news-page-image"]
```

and various other ways with no joy...I have attached a picture of the code, I am trying to target the image shaded in code.. thanks in advance for any ideas

[image]

Comment: you have to post your code or a link to this page

Comment: `.jetpack-image-container img{` this should work, try to use it then when you add style put `!important` at the end just to check that there is nothing overriding your style

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. // Both of the selectors shown would _target_ the image. Whether that has any _effect_ of course depends on what other rules might apply, and what their order and _specificity_ is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was targeting correctly but it was overwritten by some other css

Try

```
.jetpack-image-container img{
  border: 1px solid red!important;
}
```

Update:

- Try removing your browser cache (press Ctrl-F5 to force refresh)
- Make sure you are inserting css in right file, disable your caching and minify plugin for second and try

Comment: Thanks, just tried it... no joy and the strange thing is the css isn't showing on the right hand panel along with other css, even if it is being overridden

Answer (score 0):

```
.jetpack-image-container img{ ...}
```

is correct.

- Make sure you don't have any typos in your CSS
- You could try adding !important to your rules
- Double check that there aren't also @media queries which are taking precedence
- Be sure to clear your browser cache

Good luck!